# Pods-AFNetworking showing errors all of a sudden

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

I am working on an iOS App in xcode in which I used CocoaPods to install AFNetworking 3rd party library. Everything was working fine until one day I opened the xcworkspace to work on the app and I got 13 errors..even though I didn't change anything.

Here is a screenshot of the errors:

[error screenshot http://bit.ly/1ixLk1p](http://bit.ly/1ixLk1p)

Comment: Are you opening .xcodeproj instead of workspace?.

Comment: No I am opening the workspace.

Comment: hmmm so it seems that it only throws the error when the device is set to "ios device" ....so maybe not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your Podfile:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.2.0'
```

Check 'Get started' at http://cocoapods.org